# Django query to list

Tags: python, django

I have a database which has records with several fields containing some info.

To get all the data in the table matching some filter I'd do this:

```
records = Record.objects.filter(fieldA='a')
```

records, I suppose, is a QuerySet object and contains a "list" of records.  Is that correct?

Now let's say I want a list of the values in one field.

If I do this:

```
records = Record.objects.filter(fieldA='a').only('fieldB')
```

I still get a queryset, but now it has some deferred fields.  What I want is just a list of the values I meant to grab aka fieldB. I also want to be able to grab the distinct values of fieldB.  I suppose I could just iterate over each record, pull out fieldB, add it to a list if it's not already there, and there it is, but there's gotta be a better way.

Thanks!

EDIT: I think what I'm looking for is

```
Record.objects.values_list('fieldB')
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424435/how-to-convert-a-django-queryset-to-a-list

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yup, found it: `values_list`. Here's the reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Comment: That produces a list of 1-value tuples `(('a',), ('b',), ('c',))`, which probably isn't what you want. If you pass flat=True to values_list (`Record.objects.values_list('fieldB', flat=True)`) you'll get a flat list `('a', 'b', 'c')`.

Answer (score 9):

I am posting the comment by [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/121861/james-s) here to make it more prominent. It was certainly what I was looking for.

I wanted a list of values. Using the `QuerySet` method `.values_list()` returned a list of tuples. To get a list of values, I needed the option `flat=True`.

```
Record.objects.values_list('fieldB', flat=True)
```