# How to convert a Django QuerySet to a list?

Tags: django

I have the following:

```
answers = Answer.objects.filter(id__in=[answer.id for answer in answer_set.answers.all()])
```

then later:

```
for i in range(len(answers)):
    # iterate through all existing QuestionAnswer objects
    for existing_question_answer in existing_question_answers:
        # if an answer is already associated, remove it from the
        # list of answers to save
        if answers[i].id == existing_question_answer.answer.id:
            answers.remove(answers[i])           # doesn't work
            existing_question_answers.remove(existing_question_answer)
```

I get an error:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

I've tried all sorts to convert the QuerySet to a standard set or list. Nothing works.

How can I remove an item from the QuerySet so it doesn't delete it from the database, and doesn't return a new QuerySet (since it's in a loop that won't work)?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You could do this:

```
import itertools

ids = set(existing_answer.answer.id for existing_answer in existing_question_answers)
answers = itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x.id not in ids, answers)
```

Read [*when QuerySets are evaluated*](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) and note that it is not good to load the whole result into memory (e.g. via `list()`).

Reference: [`itertools.ifilter`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter)

**Update** with regard to the comment:

There are various ways to do this. One (which is probably not the best one in terms of memory and time) is to do exactly the same :

```
answer_ids = set(answer.id for answer in answers)
existing_question_answers = filter(lambda x: x.answer.id not in answers_id, existing_question_answers)
```

Comment: i've added one more line to my code sample above, deleting the same entry from exising_question_answers. is it possible to use a ifilter for that too somehow?

Comment: I'll mark this as correct because I didn't know about filter and had forgotten about lambdas.

Answer (score 489):

Why not just call `list()` on the `Queryset`?

```
answers_list = list(answers)
```

This will also evaluate the `QuerySet`/run the query. You can then remove/add from that list.

Comment: Be careful with this.  When you cast this to a a list the distinct flag may become disregarded.

Comment: I can do it independently, but I can do it in queryset in django form. Any idea why?

Comment: If so, then cast to `set` and then back to `list` to get the unique ones.

Comment: @rh0dium - do you have any reference for this? I'm using this in my code and I'm finding  it hard to understand how it might affect uniqueness (not saying it won't - just that I can't connect the dots).

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I converted the queryset to a flat values_list and then called list on the queryset. Thanks.

Answer (score 57):

It is a little hard to follow what you are really trying to do.  Your first statement looks like you may be fetching the same exact QuerySet of Answer objects twice.  First via `answer_set.answers.all()` and then again via `.filter(id__in=...)`.  Double check in the shell and see if this will give you the list of answers you are looking for:

```
answers = answer_set.answers.all()
```

Once you have that cleaned up so it is a little easier for you (and others working on the code) to read you might want to look into [.exclude()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) and the [__in](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) [field lookup](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups).

```
existing_question_answers = QuestionAnswer.objects.filter(...)

new_answers = answers.exclude(question_answer__in=existing_question_answers)
```

The above lookup might not sync up with your model definitions but it will probably get you close enough to finish the job yourself.

If you still need to get a list of id values then you want to play with [.values_list()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list).  In your case you will probably want to add the optional flat=True.

```
answers.values_list('id', flat=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I didn't provide enough detail to show that I can't use your approach.

Comment: Best solution for described problem. I want add `new_answers = answers.exclude(question_answer__in=existing_question_answers.values_list('id', flat=True))` @istruble

Answer (score 31):

By the use of slice operator with step parameter which would cause evaluation of the queryset and create a list.

```
list_of_answers = answers[::1]
```

or initially you could have done:

```
answers = Answer.objects.filter(id__in=[answer.id for answer in
        answer_set.answers.all()])[::1]
```

Comment: As far as i know, django queryset does not support negative indexing.

Comment: Okay Alexey. You are right here. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 19):

You can directly convert using the `list` keyword.
For example:

```
obj=emp.objects.all()
list1=list(obj)
```

> Using the above code you can directly convert a query set result into a `list`.

Here `list` is keyword and `obj` is result of query set and `list1` is variable in that variable we are storing the converted result which in `list`.

Comment: But if you do this it doesn't work: `list1 = list(emp.objects.all())` which seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: @geoidesic why would the above not work, when I try it works, python 3.x

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev No idea. I don't remember what I did last week, let alone 2019

Comment: @geoidesic fair enough :D take care

Answer (score 12):

Try this `values_list('column_name', flat=True)`.

```
answers = Answer.objects.filter(id__in=[answer.id for answer in answer_set.answers.all()]).values_list('column_name', flat=True)
```

It will return you a list with specified column values

Comment: Careful, I believe this still returns a Queryset. [From docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list)

Comment: It still returns QuerySet but combining from the answers above.                            answers = list(Answer.objects.filter(id__in=[answer.id for answer in answer_set.answers.all()]).values_list('column_name', flat=True)). Add the list() to convert the QuerySet to list. [Note]: This is applicable only to data that do not want a key for a result in query like me with a specific values that is needed like ID.

Answer (score 9):

Use python `list()` function

> list(). Force evaluation of a QuerySet by calling list() on it. For
> example:

```
answers = list(answer_set.answers.all())
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 7):

Why not just call 
`.values('reqColumn1','reqColumn2')` or `.values_list('reqColumn1','reqColumn2')` on the queryset?

`answers_list = models.objects.values('reqColumn1','reqColumn2')`

`result = [{'reqColumn1':value1,'reqColumn2':value2}]`

OR

`answers_list = models.objects.values_list('reqColumn1','reqColumn2')`

`result = [(value1,value2)]`

You can able to do all the operation on this QuerySet, which you do for list .

Answer (score 1):

```
def querySet_to_list(qs):
    """
    this will return python list<dict>
    """
    return [dict(q) for q in qs]

def get_answer_by_something(request):
    ss = Answer.objects.filter(something).values()
    querySet_to_list(ss) # python list return.(json-able)
```

this code convert django queryset to python list

Answer (score 1):

For me it's still giving a queryset when I use `values_list`:

```
<QuerySet [id1]>
```

so I need to complete with `list()` statment :

```
list(answers.values_list('id', flat=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `remove()` you can use `exclude()` function to remove an object from the queryset.
it's syntax is similar to `filter()`

**eg** : -

```
qs = qs.exclude(id= 1)
```

*in above code it removes all objects from qs with id '1'*

**additional info** :-

`filter()` used to select specific objects but `exclude()` used to remove