# Convert queryset to list in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a queryset with objects having fields `date` and `value`.

I need to populate the template with an array `[[date_1, value_1],[date_2,value_2],...,[date_n,value_n]]`.

How is this possible when each object has multiple fields?

I have tried

```
MyModel.objects.values_list('date', 'value')
```

but `date` is printed in datetime format (e.g. `datetime.date(2013, 9, 21)`) and value is printed as decimal (e.g. `Decimal('72495.0')`). I need it in a flot.js chart.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424435/how-to-convert-a-django-queryset-to-a-list

Answer (score 2):

```
MyModel.objects.values_list('date', 'value', flat=True)
```

[how-to-convert-a-django-queryset-to-a-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424435/how-to-convert-a-django-queryset-to-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
[(str(my_record.date), str(my_record.value)) for my_record in MyModel.objects.all()]
```

In fact, this way you can transform the data however you wish.

Answer (score 0):

```
import calendar
import json

raw_data = MyModel.objects.values_list('date', 'value')

result = []
for date, value in raw_data:
    result.append([calendar.timegm(date.timetuple()) * 1000,
                   float(value)])
```

To use result in template, serialize it to JSON first and pass `data` to template

```
data = json.dumps(result)
```

In template

```
var data = {{ data|safe }};
```

Also:

[How to convert datetime to timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4907653)

[How to serialize Decimal to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960516/python-json-serialize-a-decimal-object)