# Django - getting list of values after annotating a queryset

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a Django code like this:

```
max_id_qs = qs1.values('parent__id').\
                       annotate(max_id = Max('id'),).\
               values_list('max_id', flat = True)
```

The problem is that when I use `max_id_qs` in a filter like this:

```
rs = qs2.filter(id__in = max_id_qs)
```

the query transforms into a MySQL query of the following structure:

```
select ... from ... where ... and id in (select max(id) from ...)
```

whereas the intended result should be

```
select ... from ... where ... and id in [2342, 233, 663, ...]
```

In other words, I get subquery instead of list of integers in the MySQL query which slows down the lookup dramatically. What surprises me is that I thought that Django's `values_list` returns a list of values.

So the question, how should I rewrite the code to achieve the desired MySQL query with integers instead of `id in (select ... from...)` subquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424435/how-to-convert-a-django-queryset-to-a-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querysets are lazy, and .values_list still returns a queryset object. To evaluate it simply convert it into a list:

```
rs = qs2.filter(id__in=list(max_id_qs))
```