# If statement gives wrong output in query set

Tags: django

I'm getting the incorrect output of a query set when I use `request.method == 'POST' and selectedaccesslevel == '#'` showing as `<QuerySet ['S00009']>` when it's written to the database.

I believe I should be using a get since i'm expecting one value, but how do I filter my get on coid = owner.coid.coid and provide the value ?level?

I'm looking for my output for datareducecode to be 'S00009' and not `<QuerySet ['S00009']>.`  How can I accomplish this?  Below is my view...

```
def submitted(request):



    owner = User.objects.get (formattedusername=request.user.formattedusername)
    checkedlist = request.POST.getlist('report_id')
    print (f"checkedlist on submitted:{checkedlist}")
    access_request_date = timezone.now()

    coid = User.objects.filter(coid = request.user.coid.coid).filter(formattedusername=request.user.formattedusername)
    datareducecode = OrgLevel.objects.distinct().filter(coid=request.user.coid.coid)
#    facilitycfo =  QvDatareducecfo.objects.filter(dr_code__exact = coid, active = 1, cfo_type = 1).values_list('cfo_ntname', flat = True)
#    divisioncfo =  QvDatareducecfo.objects.filter(dr_code__exact = coid, active = 1, cfo_type = 2).values_list('cfo_ntname', flat = True)
#    print(facilitycfo)
#    print(divisioncfo)
    selectedaccesslevel = request.POST.get('accesslevelid')
    print (f"accesslevel:{selectedaccesslevel}")

    selectedphi = request.POST.get('phi')
    print (f"phi:{selectedphi}")

    print (owner.coid.coid)

    if request.method == 'POST' and selectedaccesslevel == '3':
        datareducecode = OrgLevel.objects.filter(coid__exact = owner.coid.coid).values_list('slevel', flat = True)
        print (datareducecode)
        if request.method == 'POST' and selectedaccesslevel == '4':
            datareducecode = OrgLevel.objects.filter(coid__exact = owner.coid.coid).values_list('blevel', flat = True)
            print (datareducecode)
            if request.method == 'POST' and selectedaccesslevel == '5':
                datareducecode = OrgLevel.objects.filter(coid__exact = owner.coid.coid).values_list('rlevel', flat = True)
                print (datareducecode)
                if request.method == 'POST' and selectedaccesslevel == '6':
                    datareducecode = OrgLevel.objects.filter(coid__exact = owner.coid.coid).values_list('dlevel', flat = True)
                    print (datareducecode)
                    if request.method == 'POST' and selectedaccesslevel == '7':
                        datareducecode = OrgLevel.objects.filter(coid__exact = owner.coid.coid).values_list('f"Z{Coid}"', flat = True)
                        print (datareducecode)
    else:
        datareducecode = 'No Match on Coid'
        print (datareducecode)

    for i in checkedlist:
        requestsave = QVFormAccessRequest(ntname = owner.formattedusername, first_name = owner.first_name, last_name = owner.last_name, coid = owner.coid.coid, facility = owner.facility, title = owner.title
                                          ,report_id = i, accesslevel_id = selectedaccesslevel, phi = selectedphi , access_beg_date = access_request_date, datareducecode = datareducecode )
        requestsave.save()

#    print (datareducecode)
    return JsonResponse({'is_success':True})
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `str(datareducecode)`?

Comment: just did,     print str(datareducecode)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax    Also when I try to use str(datareducecode) in requestsave = it writes to the DB as <QuerySet ['S00009']>

Comment: Okay, then you can go with `list(datareducecode)[0]` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4424460/5811078).

Comment: That worked, if you write up an answer i'll mark it correct.

Comment: Just did, thanks in advance :)

Comment: I ran a test and the only if statement that occurs correctly is the first if request.method == 'POST' and selectedaccesslevel = '3'.  When I select any of the other options 4,5,6, or 7 it writes a 'N' to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this seems to do the trick:

```
list(datareducecode)[0]
```

Comment: This will only work for the first statement in the if statement.  I dont' think these two issues are related list(datareducecode)[0] should work once the other issue is corrected.

Comment: That means that it is returning some string that begins wit `N`. Can you test it without `list`?

Comment: The issue was my if statement, i didn't have to nest it.