# Django populating table in template with two different data sets

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-queryset

I have problem. I need to populate one table with two different sets of data, one is queryset and the other is list. Is there any way to populate table with two sets of data using one `{% for %}` statement? 
Something like `{% for categories, expenses in categoriesList and expensesList %}`.

Comment: Exactly how would that go? Are `categoriesList` and `expenseList` guaranteed to have the same length? How would you *render* the data?

Comment: Is it possible to change the query set to a list too. Then maybe use the zip function to iterate over both.

Link for reference:
[Convert query set to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424435/how-to-convert-a-django-queryset-to-a-list)

Comment: They have the same length. I need to with each iteration render expenses from expensesList, its only one integer, but with categoriesList I have much more (id, description, category etc.). Ideal would be if I could include expensesList to the categoriesList, but I don't know how and if it's possible to add list to queryset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with a `zip`. In yourr view, you can prepare this with:

```
def some_view(request):
    categoriesList = …
    expensesList = …
    context = {
        'categoriesList': categoriesList,
        'expensesList': expensesList,
        'categoriesExpenses': zip(categoriesList, expensesList)
    }
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', context)
```

in the template, you can then enumerate over the `categoriesExpenses`:

```
{% for categories, expenses in categoriesExpenses %}
    …
{% endfor %}
```

that being said, if the `categoriesList` is a list of `categories` for the `expenses`, likely there are more elegant and efficient ways to do this. If there is a `ForeignKey` from the `Expense` model to the `Category` you can load these and follow the relation.

Comment: I should know about zip function at this point, thank you very much, I appreciate.